# Rails save array of ids against table row

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have a bunch of arrays matched to an `event`. I have the table called ticketmaster which is returning 6 ids like this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Ticketmasters id: 1>, #<Ticketmasters id: 1106>, #<Ticketmasters id: 1317>, #<Ticketmasters id: 4904>, #<Ticketmasters id: 11648>, #<Ticketmasters id: 13061>]>
```

Now whats im wanting is this to save against an `event` in the `events` table.

My end goal with this is to get the prices from the `ticketmasters` table and display them in a loop method in the view. I'm just struggling on how I would fully go about this?

Sam

event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_permalink :eventurl
  has_many :skiddle_tickets

  def eventurl
    "AM#{custom_event_id.scan(/.{1,4}/)[0]}" + "#{custom_event_id.scan(/.{1,4}/)[1]}" + "#{custom_event_id.scan(/.{1,4}/)[2]}" + "#{custom_event_id.scan(/.{1,4}/)[3]}"
  end

  is_impressionable
  searchkick suggest: [:eventname], batch_size: 1000, word_start: [:eventname]
end
```

ticketmaster.rb

```
class Ticketmasters < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :search_promotional_text, -> (text)         { where("promotional_text ILIKE ?", "%#{text}%") }
  scope :search_delivery_time,    -> (time)         { where("delivery_time ILIKE ?", time)}
  scope :search_product_name,     -> (product_name) { where("product_name ILIKE ?", "%#{product_name}%") }
  scope :search_valid_from,       -> (date)         { where("valid_from = ?", date) }

    class << self

      def search_by(search_options={})
        search_result = nil
        search_options.each do |k,v|
          search_result = (search_result ? search_result : self).send("search_#{k}",v)
        end
        search_result
      end

    end
end
```

Comment: Can you please add `TicketMaster` and `Event` models here?

Comment: @samnymr   paste your models.

Comment: There you both are :)